# Использовать List в другом классе

Tags: c#

Нужна помощь! У меня есть класс Readers:

```
public class Readers
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

В main-е создаю список и заполняю его:

```
List<Readers> readers = new List<Readers>();
    readers.Add(new Readers() { Name = "Дмитрий", Age = 21 });
    readers.Add(new Readers() { Name = "Марина", Age = 17 });
    readers.Add(new Readers() { Name = "Алексей", Age = 25 });
    readers.Add(new Readers() { Name = "Иван", Age = 19 });
    readers.Add(new Readers() { Name = "Анастасия", Age = 23 });
```

У меня есть другой класс, в котором мне нужно выводить это список, как это можно сделать?
Выводить нужно так:

```
foreach (Readers reader in readers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.Name + " " + reader.Age);
}
```

Comment: Ну передавайте этот список в тот метод, который должен это печатать. Либо в конструктор класса при его создании. Зависит от `use case`.

Answer (score 2):

Предположим что у ваш класс, в котором вы выводите список называется `Printer`, тогда добавьте в конструктор этого класса параметр `List<Readers> _list`

```
public class Printer
{
    private readonly List<Readers> list;
    public Printer(List<Readers> _list)
    {
        list = _list
    }
}
```

И метод `Print()`

```
public void Print()
{
    foreach (Readers reader in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.Name + " " + reader.Age);
    }
}
```

Либо измените сам метод `Print()`, добавив ему в параметр `List<Readers> list`

```
public void Print(List<Readers> list)
{
    foreach (Readers reader in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.Name + " " + reader.Age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вывод мне нужно использовать в switch-case в другом классе, как быть тогда?

Comment: Передавать список в конструктор этого класса не вариант?